# Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MariaDB client

Tags: mysql, mariadb, debian, vps, fivem

i have a vps when i try to connect to mysql server i see this error in ghmattimysql.log file

> ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication
> protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MariaDB client

my Server version: 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 Debian 10

and that's mysql.cfg file

```
set mysql_connection_string "mysql://test:testpasswd@***.***.***.**/qbus"
set mysql_debug 0
set mysql_debug_output "both"
set mysql_slow_query_warning 100
```

Comment: some one help me

Comment: suggest taking it up with the [source](https://github.com/brouznouf/fivem-mysql-async).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am currently getting this message with a codebase that used to work, so I suspect version issues.  Appreciate any insights.